# How to rewrite angular url in nginx conf to make backend call to spring using location in docker container

Tags: angular, nginx, docker-compose

I have a backend that has a controller with end points mapping "`/api`"

I have a frontend that distinguishes backend calls from angular components by using "`/server`"

So my angular service will use `http.get("/server/api/...")`

when I use npm start, I have the rewrite as below

```
{
    "/server": {
        "target": "http://localhost:8883",
        "secure": false,
    "changeOrigin": true,
    "logLevel": "debug",
    "pathRewrite": {
      "^/server" : ""
    }
    }
}
```

But when I use docker-compose, I use nginx server

```
    upstream docker-web {
        server backend:80;
    }
....
      location / {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
      }
      
      
      location /server/ { 
        # rewrite ^/server(/.*)$ $1 last; //tried this...but didnt work
        proxy_pass http://docker-web;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;  
      }
```

I commented rewrite, as I was unable to get it working. Can I ask how to fix the above i.e. dropping "server" from url by rewriting?
(can I use both proxy_pass and rewrite...or are they contradicting each other)

**ERROR: 404**

Comment: but shouldn't it be `proxy_pass http://docker-web/api` then?

Comment: This one  seems to have worked -rewrite ^/server(.*)$ $1 break;   dont know what break means, but it was redirecting

Comment: oh cool, you can self answer your question and accept it as the answer

Comment: will do. reference - https://medium.com/rahasak/nginx-reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-a3361a35623c